# Best way to reset elements to default values in the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have more than 10 elements (checkboxes) in my angular template file, which are defined only in the template and initialized with ng-init directive. Is there a nice way to reset all the checkboxes that I have in the template to the values defined in ng-init, without defining variables for each checkbox in the controller?

Comment: I don't see any other way to do it besides storing the value in your controller, or give up ng-init altogether and initialize from the controller.

Another idea could be to have a directive called "save-init" you would invoke on each checkbox like this

`<input ng-init="true" save-init ... >` 

The directive can access ng-init attribute value and store it in its isolated scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ininitialize checkboxes in controller rather than via `ngInit` directive.
I think it will be enough:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    // your prototype
    function getDefaults() {
        return {
            foo: true,
            bar: false
        };
    }

    // your real checkboxes
    $scope.model = getDefaults();

    $scope.save = function() {
        // revert model after your save/edit operations
        $scope.model = getDefaults();
    };
}
```